# trouble interpreting unicode data

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am trouble reading the file I received.  If I do `file("gtfs-l").read()` I get lines like:

`\x031.0\x10\x00\x18\xa5\x88\xc8\x98\x05\xca>\x12`

If I do `file("gtfs-l").read().encode('utf-8')` I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I do `file("gtfs-l").read().decode('utf-8')` I get an error message.  When I chop off read up to character 660 I get a bunch of Chinese, Arabic and Japanese characters which is wrong since I am reading from an American source:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_16.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode bytes in position 666-667: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

Here is the original file.  I can tell you got it from using GTFS data from the [NYC subway](http://datamine.mta.info/list-of-feeds).

```
'\n"\n\x031.0\x10\x00\x18\xa5\x88\xc8\x98\x05\xca>\x12\n\x031.0\x12\x0b\n\x01L\x12\x06\x10\xad\x96\xc8\x98\x05\x12w\n\x011\x1ar\n2\n\x0b064500_L..S\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1045 MYR/RPY\x10\x01\x18\x03\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xbd\x88\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xcc\x88\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L28S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\xf9\x88\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L29S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12C\n\x012">\n2\n\x0b064500_L..S\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1045 MYR/RPY\x10\x01\x18\x03\x18\x16 \x01(\x8d\x88\xc8\x98\x05\x12\x9b\x01\n\x013\x1a\x95\x01\n2\n\x0b064800_L..N\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1048 RPY/MYR\x10\x01\x18\x01\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xa0\x88\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xaf\x88\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L20N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x97\x89\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xa6\x89\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L19N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\xeb\x89\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L17N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12C\n\x014">\n2\n\x0b064800_L..N\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1048 RPY/MYR\x10\x01\x18\x01\x18\x08 \x01(\xfe\x87\xc8\x98\x05\x12\xa7\x02\n\x015\x1a\xa1\x02\n2\n\x0b065300_L..S\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1053 MYR/RPY\x10\x01\x18\x03\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x8d\x88\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x9c\x88\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L22S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xd9\x88\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xe8\x88\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L24S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xb3\x89\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xc2\x89\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L25S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xef\x89\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xfe\x89\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L26S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xc9\x8a\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xd8\x8a\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L27S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xc1\x8b\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xd0\x8b\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L28S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\xfd\x8b\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L29S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12C\n\x016">\n2\n\x0b065300_L..S\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1053 MYR/RPY\x10\x01\x18\x03\x18\x11 \x01(\xfe\x87\xc8\x98\x05\x12\xca\x02\n\x017\x1a\xc4\x02\n2\n\x0b065600_L..N\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1056 RPY/MYR\x10\x01\x18\x01\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xea\x88\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xf9\x88\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L26N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xc4\x89\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xd3\x89\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L25N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x9e\x8a\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xad\x8a\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L24N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xf8\x8a\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x87\x8b\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L22N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xb4\x8b\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xc3\x8b\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L21N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x8e\x8c\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x9d\x8c\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L20N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x86\x8d\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x95\x8d\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L19N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\xda\x8d\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L17N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12C\n\x018">\n2\n\x0b065600_L..N\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1056 RPY/MYR\x10\x01\x18\x01\x18\x03 \x02(\x9c\x88\xc8\x98\x05\x12\xb3\x03\n\x019\x1a\xad\x03\n2\n\x0b066100_L..S\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1101 MYR/RPY\x10\x01\x18\x03\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xad\x88\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xbc\x88\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L17S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x87\x89\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x96\x89\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L19S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x9d\x8a\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xac\x8a\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L20S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xf7\x8a\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x86\x8b\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L21S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xb3\x8b\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xc2\x8b\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L22S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xef\x8b\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xfe\x8b\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L24S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xc9\x8c\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xd8\x8c\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L25S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x85\x8d\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x94\x8d\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L26S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xdf\x8d\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xee\x8d\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L27S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xd7\x8e\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xe6\x8e\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L28S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\x93\x8f\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L29S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12D\n\x0210">\n2\n\x0b066100_L..S\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1101 MYR/RPY\x10\x01\x18\x03\x18\r \x01(\x9e\x88\xc8\x98\x05\x12\xac\x03\n\x0211\x1a\xa5\x03\n2\n\x0b066400_L..N\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1104 RPY/MYR\x10\x01\x18\x01\x12\x19\x1a\x06\x10\xf0\x89\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L29N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xbb\x8a\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xca\x8a\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L28N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xb3\x8b\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xc2\x8b\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L27N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x8d\x8c\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x9c\x8c\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L26N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xe7\x8c\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xf6\x8c\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L25N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xc1\x8d\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xd0\x8d\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L24N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x9b\x8e\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xaa\x8e\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L22N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xd7\x8e\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xe6\x8e\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L21N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xb1\x8f\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xc0\x8f\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L20N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xa9\x90\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xb8\x90\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L19N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\xfd\x90\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L17N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12D\n\x0212">\n2\n\x0b066400_L..N\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1104 RPY/MYR\x10\x01\x18\x01\x18\x00 \x01(\x9e\x88\xc8\x98\x05\x12\xb4\x03\n\x0213\x1a\xad\x03\n2\n\x0b066900_L..S\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1109 MYR/RPY\x10\x00\x18\x03\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x8d\x8c\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x9c\x8c\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L17S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xe7\x8c\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xf6\x8c\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L19S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xfd\x8d\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x8c\x8e\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L20S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xd7\x8e\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xe6\x8e\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L21S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x93\x8f\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xa2\x8f\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L22S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xcf\x8f\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xde\x8f\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L24S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xa9\x90\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xb8\x90\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L25S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xe5\x90\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xf4\x90\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L26S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xbf\x91\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xce\x91\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L27S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xb7\x92\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xc6\x92\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L28S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\xf3\x92\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L29S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12\xac\x03\n\x0215\x1a\xa5\x03\n2\n\x0b067200_L..N\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1112 RPY/MYR\x10\x00\x18\x01\x12\x19\x1a\x06\x10\xd0\x8d\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L29N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x9b\x8e\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xaa\x8e\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L28N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x93\x8f\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xa2\x8f\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L27N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xed\x8f\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xfc\x8f\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L26N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xc7\x90\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xd6\x90\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L25N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xa1\x91\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xb0\x91\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L24N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xfb\x91\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x8a\x92\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L22N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xb7\x92\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xc6\x92\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L21N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x91\x93\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xa0\x93\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L20N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x89\x94\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x98\x94\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L19N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\xdd\x94\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L17N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12\xb4\x03\n\x0217\x1a\xad\x03\n2\n\x0b067700_L..S\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1117 MYR/RPY\x10\x00\x18\x03\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xed\x8f\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xfc\x8f\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L17S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xc7\x90\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xd6\x90\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L19S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xdd\x91\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xec\x91\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L20S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xb7\x92\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xc6\x92\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L21S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xf3\x92\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x82\x93\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L22S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xaf\x93\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xbe\x93\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L24S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x89\x94\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x98\x94\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L25S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xc5\x94\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xd4\x94\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L26S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x9f\x95\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xae\x95\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L27S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x97\x96\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xa6\x96\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L28S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\xd3\x96\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L29S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12\xac\x03\n\x0219\x1a\xa5\x03\n2\n\x0b068000_L..N\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1120 RPY/MYR\x10\x00\x18\x01\x12\x19\x1a\x06\x10\xb0\x91\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L29N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xfb\x91\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x8a\x92\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L28N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xf3\x92\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x82\x93\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L27N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xcd\x93\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xdc\x93\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L26N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xa7\x94\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xb6\x94\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L25N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x81\x95\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x90\x95\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L24N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xdb\x95\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xea\x95\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L22N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x97\x96\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xa6\x96\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L21N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xf1\x96\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x80\x97\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L20N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xe9\x97\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xf8\x97\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L19N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\xbd\x98\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L17N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12\xb4\x03\n\x0221\x1a\xad\x03\n2\n\x0b068500_L..S\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1125 MYR/RPY\x10\x00\x18\x03\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xcd\x93\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xdc\x93\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L17S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xa7\x94\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xb6\x94\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L19S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xbd\x95\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xcc\x95\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L20S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x97\x96\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xa6\x96\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L21S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xd3\x96\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xe2\x96\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L22S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x8f\x97\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x9e\x97\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L24S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xe9\x97\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xf8\x97\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L25S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xa5\x98\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xb4\x98\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L26S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xff\x98\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x8e\x99\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L27S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xf7\x99\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x86\x9a\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L28S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\xb3\x9a\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L29S(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x011\x12\x011\x12\xac\x03\n\x0223\x1a\xa5\x03\n2\n\x0b068800_L..N\x1a\x0820140301*\x01L\xca>\x15\n\x0f0L 1128 RPY/MYR\x10\x00\x18\x01\x12\x19\x1a\x06\x10\x90\x95\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L29N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xdb\x95\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xea\x95\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L28N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xd3\x96\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xe2\x96\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L27N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xad\x97\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xbc\x97\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L26N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\x87\x98\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x96\x98\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L25N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xe1\x98\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xf0\x98\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L24N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xbb\x99\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xca\x99\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L22N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xf7\x99\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\x86\x9a\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L21N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xd1\x9a\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xe0\x9a\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L20N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12!\x12\x06\x10\xc9\x9b\xc8\x98\x05\x1a\x06\x10\xd8\x9b\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L19N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012\x12\x19\x12\x06\x10\x9d\x9c\xc8\x98\x05"\x04L17N(\x00\xca>\x06\n\x012\x12\x012'
```

Comment: What encoding is the data supposed to be in?  According to [this page](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/) the GTFS data is "a series of text files collected in a ZIP file", so you'll need to unzip it.  (Not sure if that documentation is for the same feed you used, but it seems likely.)

Comment: You certainly do not have UTF-8 data there, that is a binary format.